# SplitContainer splitter movement is not visible on WebView control

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2, splitter, splitcontainer

I have datagridview and webview2 in splitcontainer.(orientation=horizontal, dock=fill)

After placing the textbox instead of webview2, if I grab the splitter with the mouse and move it, the splitter's movement is visible.

But when I place the webview2 in the splitcontainer, the splitter's movement disappears and is not visible.

Is it possible to make the splitter's movement visible on the webview2 area placed in the splitcontainer?

[image: splitter disppears on webview2]

Comment: What does _visible_ mean in the context of _"the splitter's movement disappears and is not visible"_?

Comment: @Flydog57 splitcontainer has a splitter that can be resized, and when we hold and drag it with the mouse, we can see the splitter movement in real time.

Comment: Does it move (and just be invisible while it's moving) or something else?

Comment: @Flydog57 The splitter performs resizing successfully, but the movement of the splitter bar just disappears ont the webview2 area.

Comment: Does it reappear once you move and release the mouse?

Comment: @Flydog57 The process of dragging the splitter to the webview2 area is not visible, but is shown when released.

Comment: That's very likely an unavoidable behavior (I don't know for sure, but...). The browser control is complex and resizing it dynamically with an animation is probably more work than the implemters thought was worth it.

Comment: While keeping it open here, I'd suggest you post an issue here as well: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues

Comment: @RezaAghaei As you advised, I will raise an issue on that page as well.